# What should I do if I want to show the following equation may be related to the modified Bessel function?

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I have found the following equation may related to the modified Bessel function of the first kind, but how to prove it?
The equation is as follows:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\Gamma(T)\exp\{-||y||^{2}\}}{\pi^{T}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\{-z(\rho T+1)\}}{(||y||\sqrt{\rho Tz})^{T-1}}I_{T-1}(2||y||\sqrt{\rho Tz})dz\\
=& \frac{e^{-||y||^{2}/(1+\rho T)}||y||^{2(1-T)}\Gamma(T)}{\pi^{T}(1+\rho T)}\tilde{\gamma}(T-1,\frac{\rho T||y||^{2}}{1+\rho T})(1+\frac{1}{\rho T})^{T-1}
\end{align}
where $||y||$ denotes the $l_{2}$-norm of $y$, $\tilde{\gamma}(\cdot,\cdot)$ represents the lower incomplete gamma function and $I_{T-1}(\cdot)$ the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

How should I verify the above equation ?

Any useful suggestion is welcome.

Thanks a lot, Liu.